# Date between with only the days and month

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this date :

```
Date1 =  14/10/2015
Date2 =  01/10/2011
Date3 =  01/11/2011
```

I'm trying to make this req :

```
Date1 between date2 and date3
```

How can i make this without paying attention to the years (only sql (oracle)).

The req should be true.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In *Oracle* you can get first day of month for `date1` and `date2` and last day of month for `date3` then use between, something like:

```
WHERE TRUNC(date1, 'MONTH') BETWEEN TRUNC(date2, 'MONTH') AND LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(date3,'MM/DD/YYYY'))
```

Comment: `TRUNC( date, 'MONTH' )` will truncate to the first day of the month but will not ignore the year component.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could just cast the numeric representation of `MMDD` to a number, and check if this number is in a specific range.

```
select *
from (select to_date('14/10/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY') as datee from dual union
      select to_date('01/10/2011', 'DD/MM/YYYY') as datee from dual union
      select to_date('01/11/2011', 'DD/MM/YYYY') as datee from dual)
where to_number(to_char(datee,'MMDD')) between 1014 and 1131
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you can use the [`EXTRACT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions059.htm#SQLRF00639) function to get individual parts of the date and use that to compare:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dbbd9/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST( Date1 ) AS
          SELECT DATE '2015-01-01' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-01-15' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-02-01' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-09-01' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2014-01-10' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2014-01-20' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2014-02-02' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2013-01-14' FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH Dates ( Date2, Date3 ) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2015-01-10', DATE '2015-02-01' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT t.*
FROM   TEST t
       CROSS JOIN Dates d
WHERE  (  EXTRACT( MONTH FROM Date1 ) > EXTRACT( MONTH FROM Date2 )
       OR (    EXTRACT( MONTH FROM Date1 ) =  EXTRACT( MONTH FROM Date2 )
           AND EXTRACT( DAY   FROM Date1 ) >= EXTRACT( DAY   FROM Date2 )
          )
       )
AND    (  EXTRACT( MONTH FROM Date1 ) < EXTRACT( MONTH FROM Date3 )
       OR (    EXTRACT( MONTH FROM Date1 ) =  EXTRACT( MONTH FROM Date3 )
           AND EXTRACT( DAY   FROM Date1 ) <= EXTRACT( DAY   FROM Date3 )
          )
       )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dbbd9/3/0)**:

```
|                      DATE1 |
|----------------------------|
|  January, 15 2015 00:00:00 |
| February, 01 2015 00:00:00 |
|  January, 10 2014 00:00:00 |
|  January, 20 2014 00:00:00 |
|  January, 14 2013 00:00:00 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DDD` format string to get the number of the day of the year, i.e.:

```
select to_char(to_date('14/10/2015','DD/MM/YYYY'),'DDD') d1
      ,to_char(to_date('01/10/2011','DD/MM/YYYY'),'DDD') d2
      ,to_char(to_date('01/11/2011','DD/MM/YYYY'),'DDD') d3
from dual;

D1  D2  D3
=== === ===
287 274 305

with params as (
  select to_date('14/10/2015','DD/MM/YYYY') d1
        ,to_date('01/10/2011','DD/MM/YYYY') d2
        ,to_date('01/11/2011','DD/MM/YYYY') d3
  from dual)
select 'Yes' a from params
where to_char(d1,'DDD') between to_char(d2,'DDD') and to_char(d3,'DDD');

A
===
Yes
```